# UIApplication sharedApplication instance is same as given in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Tags: ios, uiapplication

Is the instance of **UIApplication** given in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is same as **[UIApplication sharedApplication]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are the same, for `UIApplication` is a singleton; the message `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` returns that singleton object and so does `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.